AC Circuit Analysis with Square Wave and Transmission Line
I'd like to solve the AC analysis for a circuit with a square-wave function (with a DC offset, so it goes from 0V to some positive voltage with each step) in series with a resistor and a shorted transmission line.  And specifically, I'd like to be able to plot the voltage across the resistor as a function of time.  Basically this setup:
https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjOCmC0YEzgMwDoAMBOA7AFjAVkTjFQA4wSA2CPVEPO2vGMMAKDEwg4vHQW3Q8wfELRSoJkqdOwx04CSBK1UrAO7g4JEHEwJuOvaPUgBQkXmzZeCVRrOGEl67tusA5pu2uvOktpVWACUQQRsQCmthWx0laTEQRFFRZDwTZ3CMn1UAJ1DzfUwC5PxVAHs6COtabAxtYhSIGsqkzGS2xFYgA
but for arbitrary resistance, square-wave frequency and voltage, and characteristic transmission line impedance.

Are you familiar with the transmission line bounce diagram?

@TimWilliams, I was vaguely familiar with them, but looking them up again, seems like this is maybe what I want, thanks!

Excellent -- you might consider answering your own question with what you've learned about this topic, then; or find other questions here with which to close it as duplicate. (Regarding the close, it seems erroneous as the question is clearly focused on one well-understood topic; I don't know why it was voted as such.)

Just use a simulator with "click" an "adjust" value with mouse ...
Enjoy clicking with mouse on the "define" statement and adjust value with "up" and "down" arrows.
Made with microcap v12


I guess what I should have said in my question is that I'd like to know the underlying equation such a simulator is using to make that plot and how to derive it

The analytical problem of studying the propagation of electrical energy with any time course, along a line, in general, is very complicated. With the use of the Laplace transform it is relatively simplified as can be seen from the attached photos even if it refers to a line of infinite length.














